# How to show UIKeyboard upon tapping a button?

Tags: iphone, ios, uikeyboard

I want to show the `UIKeyboard` upon tapping a `UIButton` and display the text (typed by the user) on a `UILabel`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a hidden UITextField, and set it as firstResponder. As you inputing any chars, copy those chars from hidden UITextField to UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just replace the label with an appropriately-styled (visible) UITextField? Then swap it back when the user taps the button again (or a Done button somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

This is sorta the opposite of what you want, but this this you can just mess with the code and have it make the keyboard visible on buttonpress. Also in this example, the change is triggered when the user touches the background. You can just set this to whatever button you want instead of the background.

**Hiding the Keyboard when the User Taps the Background**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface hideKeyboardViewController : UIViewController {
        UITextField    *textField;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
- (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender;
@end
```

Select the `hideKeyboardViewController.m` file and implement the action by calling the `resignFirstResponder` method of our textField object:

```
#import "hideKeyboardViewController.h"
@implementation hideKeyboardViewController
@synthesize textField;
-(IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender
{
        [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
-(IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender
{
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
.
.
@end
```

[More on this subject here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Writing_iOS_4_Code_to_Hide_the_iPhone_Keyboard_%28Xcode_4%29)